# Joining two tables and iterating through data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I constantly am using stackoverflow to help me but right now I am stumped - hopefully I can get some guidance on this issue:

I have two tables, one containing NFL Divisions the other containing NFL Teams. They are connected via the division_id field (primary key on Divisions table, foreign key on the Teams table).

What I would like to do is join the tables in a query and output the Teams by Division. I can accomplish this in PHP with two separate queries/loops but I want to know how/if I can accomplish this by joining the two tables in a single query instead.

Here is what I've got:

```
$query = "SELECT Divisions.division_id, Divisions.conference, Divisions.name, 
    Teams.name FROM Divisions INNER JOIN Teams ON 
    Teams.division_id = Divisions.division_id ORDER BY Divisions.division_id";

if( $result = $db->query($query) ){
  while( $row = $result->fetch_object() ){
    // here is where I'm stuck
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the final output to look similar to:

**AFC North**
Cleveland Browns
Pittsburgh Steelers
Baltimore Ravens
Cincinnati Bengals

**AFC East**
Buffalo Bills
Miami Dolphins
etc..

Major thank you in advance to anyone who can help me out with this! I haven't done any programming in over 2 years and just getting back into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the rows and output a new header whenever the `division_id` changes:

```
$query = "SELECT Divisions.division_id, Divisions.conference, Divisions.name, 
    Teams.name AS teamName FROM Divisions INNER JOIN Teams ON 
    Teams.division_id = Divisions.division_id ORDER BY Divisions.division_id";

if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    $division = "";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        if ($division != $row["division_id"])
        {
            $division = $row["division_id"];
            echo "<br /><h2>{$row["conference"]}</h2>";
        }

        echo "{$row["teamName"]}<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
if( $result = $db->query($query) ){

  while( $row = $result->fetch_object() ){
    if(empty($result[$row['division_id']])
    {
       $result[$row['division_id']] = $row;
    }
    $result[$row['division_id']]['teams'][] = $row;
  }
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop trough and check if it is the same division again.
if its a new division, write it and `<br />`

```
$query = "SELECT Divisions.division_id, Divisions.conference, Divisions.name, 
    Teams.name as teamName FROM Divisions INNER JOIN Teams ON 
    Teams.division_id = Divisions.division_id ORDER BY Divisions.division_id";

if( $result = $db->query($query) ){
    $lastDivision = -1;
  while( $row = $result->fetch_object() ){
    if($lastDivision != $row["division_id"]){
        //here it is a new division,
        echo "<b>" . $row["division_id"] . "</b><br />";
    }else{
        //not a new division so we just continu to write teams
        echo $row["teamName"] . "<br />";
    }
    $lastDivision = $row["division_id"];
  }
}
```