# How to sort through large multidimensional array from MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

I have a MySQL table which contains a list of all possible products a customer can order. A (very) simplified version of this table would look like:

```
ID  |  productid    |    price    |   age_min   |   age_max   |   type
=======================================================================
1   |   baseball_1  |    12.34    |    18       |    21       |    1
2   |   baseball_2  |    15.99    |    22       |    30       |    1
3   |   baseball_3  |    18.99    |    18       |    99       |    1
4   |   golf_1      |    4.99     |    18       |    24       |    2
5   |   golf_2      |    5.99     |    25       |    44       |    2
6   |   tennis_1    |    9.99     |    18       |    50       |    3
7   |   tennis_2    |    14.99    |    51       |    99       |    3
```

In this store, all products are age banded, meaning a customer can only select an item to purchase if his/her age fits in that range. A custom can only select one "type" even if multiple options exist per product "type". In the example table above, a customer who is 24 years old would only be able to select:

> baseball_2, baseball_3 golf_1, and tennis_1

I am trying to lay out the options a potential customer has, organized by known product types. So in my case, the store may show the customer:

### Baseball Option

- baseball_2 - $15.99
- baseball_3 - $18.99

### Golf Option

- golf_1 - $4.99

### Tennis Option

- tennis_1 - $9.99

I want to make a single (if possible) MySQL call to the database with the age variable and return all possible products then display these products accordingly as mentioned above. The SQL statement is simple and I already have this accomplished but I am not sure how to cycle though or build a proper array which could list out the available options for a member.

It may be suggested but this is much more detailed than shown and using any type of third party software or shopping cart is not an option due to several other factors unrelated o the question. It seems this is a question in how to deal with multidimensional arrays. Has anybody faced a similar problem before?

---

### UPDATE

while the solutions provided below by Travesty and tdammer are valid in some circumstances, I want to be able to do more with my data then just display it as it comes out of my database. The layout and design of the page should not depend on how/when/etc it is stored in the database. There may be times I want to show the highest price first for one set of "types" while the lowest first for another.

By using a fetchAll statement, I am able to collect all of the necessary data I need from my query but I am really uncertain as how to make use of it. For example, my array is currently:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [productid] => 394, [price] => 6.20,  [type] => 16 ),
    [1] => Array ( [productid] => 395, [price] => 12.40, [type] => 16 ),
    [2] => Array ( [productid] => 396, [price] => 18.60, [type] => 16 ),
    [3] => Array ( [productid] => 397, [price] => 24.80, [type] => 16 ),
    [4] => Array ( [productid] => 398, [price] => 31.00, [type] => 16 ),
    [5] => Array ( [productid] => 449, [price] => 4.20,  [type] => 17 ),
    [6] => Array ( [productid] => 450, [price] => 8.40,  [type] => 17 ),
    [7] => Array ( [productid] => 451, [price] => 12.60, [type] => 17 ),
    [8] => Array ( [productid] => 452, [price] => 16.80, [type] => 17 ),
    [9] => Array ( [productid] => 453, [price] => 21.00, [type] => 17 )
)
```

Is there a good way to build my own array in a manner I would later be able to essentially say "Show me the productid and price of all items with type 17"?

Comment: Are you sure that multidimensional arrays are really what you're looking for? I have seen questions similar to this many times, and just answered another one this morning: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10501112/259457. Is that what you're having trouble with?

Comment: @Travesty3 - I'm not coming from two tables as your original poster and still somewhat different, although I believe the way you change headers is very interesting and perhaps what I am trying to get to. I'll play around with it for a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need multidimensional arrays for this. I think you just need to loop through your rows and change your header when you come to a new group.

I used a little bit different of an approach for this answer, to stick each line into an array and then implode them so formatting is preserved.

```
//USING PDO - assume connection already made
/* added ORDER BY in the query to ensure that we get the rows sequentially, by type */
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE age_min >= :age AND age_max <= :age ORDER BY type");
$stmt->bindParam(":age", $customer_age);
$stmt->execute();

$type = -1;
$lines = array();
while ($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $data = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $data); /* sanitize data for HTML output */

    if ($type != $data["type"])
    {
        $type = $data["type"];
        list($typeName) = explode("_", $data["productid"]); /* this assumes that you don't have a column with the actual product name. If you do, use that instead. */
        $lines[] = (count($lines) > 0 ? "</ul>\n" : "") ."<h2>". ucfirst($typeName) ." Option</h2>\n<ul>";
    }

    $lines[] = "\t<li>{$data["productid"]} - {$data["price"]}</li>";
}

echo implode("\n", $lines) ."\n</ul>";
```

---

**Response to question update:**

> Is there a good way to build my own array in a manner I would later be able to essentially say "Show me the productid and price of all items with type 17"?

That is a query. I still see no reason to store it in an array. If you want to get the productid and price of all items with type 17, then you should perform that query on the database. If you want to order your results differently, then you should change your `ORDER BY` clause.

Perhaps you need to adjust your query so that it is a bit more flexible:

```
if (!isset($_POST["columns"]))
    $_POST["columns"] = "productid, price";
if (!isset($_POST["whereClause"]))
    $_POST["whereClause"] = "TRUE";
if (!isset($_POST["orderby"]))
    $_POST["orderby"] = "type ASC, price DESC";

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT :columns FROM table WHERE age_min >= :age AND age_max <= :age AND :whereClause ORDER BY :orderby");
$stmt->bindParam(":columns", $_POST["columns"]);
$stmt->bindParam(":age", $customer_age);
$stmt->bindParam(":whereClause", $_POST["whereClause"]);
$stmt->bindParam(":orderby", $_POST["orderby"]);
$stmt->execute();
```

You can call this either with an HTML form submission (causing a page reload) or you can call it via AJAX. But either way, I don't see how doing a `fetchAll` and storing the results in an array does you any good at all.

Comment: I'm a little OCD when it comes to my HTML output having good formatting (tabs, newlines, etc.), so that's the reason for the `\n` and `\t` in the strings. Makes it easier to figure out what's going wrong when having problems when you run the PHP script and then view source to see the actual HTML that is produced.

Comment: You should rather be OCD about properly *escaping* your HTML output. PHP certainly doesn't make your life easy, but if you don't use `htmlspecialchars()` and friends appropriately, you *deserve* to be XSS'd.

Comment: I'm thinking about it a little more and although I'll go ahead with this answer - it greatly limits my ability to transpose the data. At this point, it is all about how I have things stored in the database. For example, if I **knew** a customer header would contain several items (say Baseball and Golf were to be listed together) then this option doesn't really help me out. I'll have to mess with it some.

Comment: @tdammers: Yes, it certainly wouldn't hurt to sanitize with `htmlspecialchars()`, but I was assuming that the data from the database is maintained by an admin, not from user input.

Comment: @JM4: I had forgotten to post the edit I made to the query. You should also add `ORDER BY type` to your query so that you get the rows in that order. That way you ensure that all rows with the same type go under the same heading. See updated answer.

Comment: @Travesty3: It doesn't matter. A database stores text. A web browser expects HTML. Those two, even though unfortunately represented as the same data type in PHP, are not interchangeable. You don't want HTML in your database, and you don't want plain strings to break your HTML on the web browser either.

Comment: @tdammers - I have never once used htmlspecialcharacters after retrieving strings from a database (nor I have seen it documented to do such). I don't discount the XSS capabilities of improperly escaping and whatnot but I don't see how it provides any real benefit here. Also, array_map **can** have some unfavorable side issues if trying to modify your returned data in other ways.

Comment: @JM4: the point is not that you escape things after retrieving them from a database. The point is that what you have are raw strings, and what you want to output is HTML. They are not the same thing, and even though you may get away with it in many cases, it is not technically correct - you need to convert the one into the other, otherwise character sequences that have a different meaning in HTML than they do in plain text will break your output. Just wait until you have a customer named O'Brien looking at a pre-filled form input.

Comment: @JM4: I updated my answer in response to your updated question.

Comment: @Travesty3 - having all the data in a single call to the database allows me to make one call, not several successive ones, to get the data I ultimately need and will use on more than one page during a form process.

Comment: No matter how you try - there is no sorting for "random" and the client wants an order on various pages which would be impossible to generate from a single query in MySQL.

Comment: @JM4: If I understand correctly, it sounds like you want to pull the data from the database once, display it in multiple pages to the user, and if the user changes the sorting on, for example, page 2, it only changes the order of the items displayed on page 2, and not all of the items. Is that right? If so, perhaps you could store the items for each page in Javascript arrays (one array for each page) and then [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them individually. Would that do what you want?

Comment: @JM4: Are you trying to get a product listing, similar to something like [BestBuy.com](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Laptop-Computers/PC+Laptops/pcmcat247400050000.c?id=pcmcat247400050000), where you can narrow your results and change sorting and number of results per page, and that kind of thing?

Comment: @Travesty - I'm on the road right now but let me get back and rewrite the question to better highlight the issue. It is not a customer sorting issue, it lies in the way our management wants things not only sorted and displayed on a page but from a programming perspective, it does not make sense to need to go to the database several times when one call **might** work.

Comment: @Travesty3 - I still want to try and figure out a way to store this data but also learned about using a CASE statement in ORDER BY clauses so this may actually suffice for time being. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a multidimensional array for this.

Just order your query results by type, then cycle through the array. While doing so, insert a heading before the first item and then before every item at which the type changes.

If you have a properly normalized database, you should also have a `product_types` table that holds your product type ID's and names; in this case, consider a `JOIN`. You SQL would then look somewhat like this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.price, t.id AS type_id, t.name AS type_name FROM products AS p LEFT JOIN product_types t ON t.id = p.type WHERE :age BETWEEN p.min_age AND p.max_age;
```

And then, you step through your result set something like this:

```
$current_type = 'not_a_string';
while ($row = get_next_row_from_database) {
    if ($current_type !== $row['type_id']) {
        echo '<h3>' . htmlspecialchars($row['type_name']) . '</h3>';
        $current_type = $row['type_id'];
    }
    printf('<p>%s - $%2.2f</p>', htmlspecialchars($row['name']), $row['price']);
}
```

This approach uses constant memory (on the web server, not on the database obviously) and linear time.

You should also consider pagination of your data: don't query all the rows at once, instead, run a `COUNT(*)` query to get the total number of rows, and then use `LIMIT` to get only the rows for the current page (you probably also want to specify an `ORDER BY` clause to make your pages meaningful).

Comment: while my question may have lead to the belief I just needed to output the data once, I really have many uses for it and the method you and travesty both mention gives very little flexibility given it is just sorting through the rows. I have been testing for hours but it really isn't working as needed. I am thinking a multidimensional array is in fact the way I'll need to go with it. (your method only allows me to output as it comes, not place specific types, prices, etc over the page as needed).the method Job Brown describes below is ultimately the right now things will need to be.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your database, this solution may not work, but generally how I work on a smaller scale is:

Loop the database results into an array of my design

So I might have

```
Array['baseball'][0]['price'] = 15.99
Array['baseball'][1]['price'] = 18.99
```

Loop through the array I've created to parse results.

In a larger database, you'll need a different solution as this will leave you looping result results multiple times ...